# cerrar una pestaña de google chrome con java en automatizacion

Tags: java, chrome

tengo una duda hace ya unos días estoy programando para automatizar una prueba en un portal académico, el mismo consta en presionar un modulo y que me abra una pagina externa, hasta ahí todo bien el tema es que estoy necesitando cerrar la pestaña de la pagina emergente de manera automática y no estoy encontrando la forma, la única que encontré al momento es driver.close(); pero esto me cierra el explorador entero, la otra que hice fue hacer un change.focus para luego cerrar sesión pero el test me tira error, no se si habrá forma de cerrar la pestaña que quiero cerrar y luego seguir trabajando dentro de la pagina principal.

gracias

Comment: Puede que la función window.close() te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar el Selenium Driver:

```
driver.closeWindow();
```

Para poder cerrar la pestaña, pero antes de cerrarla debes de asegurarte, de haber obtenido la pestaña que deseas cerrar.
Tambien encuentra en el siguiente link una respuesta similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449179/how-can-i-close-a-specific-window-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Probablemente _se te fue_ la oración extra en inglés: recuerda que estamos en [es.so] :)

Comment: Cierto, ya quedo corregido